# How to show $\phi^*$ is finite and differentiable?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am studying [Mirror descent and nonlinear projected subgradient methods](https://web.iem.technion.ac.il/images/user-files/becka/papers/3.pdf). At page 170 proposition 3.1, part d, the author claims that $\phi^*$ is finite and differentiable if and only if the inverse map $(\partial \phi)^{-1}$ is everywhere single valued and Lipschitz continuous with $\sigma^{-1}$ where $\phi {}:{} \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$ be a proper convex and Lipschitz function and $\sigma >0$.

> Show $\phi^*$ is finite and differentiable if and only if the inverse map $(\partial \phi)^{-1}$ is everywhere single valued and Lipschitz continuous with $\sigma^{-1}$.

$\phi^*$ is conjugate function which is defined as below:
$$
\phi^*(z) = \sup_x {}\{ \langle x,z\rangle - \phi(x)\}.
$$

Comment: They cite the book of Rockafellar and Wets. Do you have access to that?

Comment: @Pantelis Sopasakis: I do but I wanted to have the proof in simple wording here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $\sigma$ is not the Lipschitz constant of $\phi$. It is the strong convexity modulus of $\phi$, if $\phi$ is assumed to be strongly convex.

If $\phi^*$ is finite everywhere and differentiable, its subdifferential,

$$
\partial \phi^*(x) = \{\nabla \phi^*(x)\}
$$

for all $x$. But $v\in \partial \phi(x)$ is equivalent to $x \in \partial \phi^*(v)$ (since $\phi$ is assumed to be proper, convex and lsc). Therefore, $\partial \phi^* = (\partial \phi)^{-1}$, which is single-valued.

Conversely, we want to prove that if $(\partial \phi)^{-1}$ is everywhere single-valued, then $\phi^*$ is everywhere finite and differentiable. To that end we use the fact that $\phi = \phi^{**}$ (because $\phi$ is assumed to be proper and lsc) and we apply what we showed above.

The rest of your question has to do with the Lipschitz constant of $(\partial \phi)^{-1}$ being $1/\sigma$ when $\phi$ is $\sigma$-strongly convex. By definition, $\phi$ is $\sigma$-strongly convex if $\phi-\tfrac{\sigma}{2}\|{}\cdot{}\|^2$ is convex. It is easy to show that $\phi$ is strongly convex if and only if $\partial \phi$ is strongly monotone. Then, we apply Proposition 12.54 in the book of Rockafellar and Wets to complete the proof.

Comment: Could you explain why $v \in \partial \phi(x)$ is equivalent to $x\in \partial \phi^*(v)$? What fact you are using to get this? I would appreciate if show me how you get this using the definition.

Comment: @Saeed I will update my answer later tonight or tomorrow. If you have access to Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis" you can find this in Chapter 23.

Comment: I will appreciate if you update your answer.